# I am trying to build docker image for my discord bot i keep encountering the below error

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, docker, discord.js

Since I cant paste the error here, because StackOverflow marks it as spam -
I keep getting either gyp error or sqlite3 error or python error:

```
FROM node:16.13-alpine3.15

RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual .builds-deps build-base python3

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["node", ".", "--trace-warnings"]
```

{https://pastebin.com/ZaRpnK5i}

Comment: it is most probably node version error.  Try changing the node version from 16.13. You should look if the packages in package.json are compatible with your node version.

Comment: Thankyou so much hassan it is indeed the node version. when i used node:16.9.1-buster it actually worked and now my image is build